# Tokens expiring after a couple of weeks

Tags: oauth2-playground

We are generating tokens through the Oauth2 playground using our own credentials. The option, Auto-refresh the token before it expires, is selected. The app is in test. The tokens expire every couple of weeks. Why are the tokens expiring? Thanks.